# IE table alignment issue

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, html-table

I am working in a scenario where I need a column to occupy full height of the corresponding cell, even though content of the column isn't has enough data to occupy full cell. I have attached a link of codepen. It has two columns. Column 1 has less data than column 2. Data in the column in vertical aligned based on the height of the current row, but I need column 1 to occupy full height of cell.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/pravinkumart/pen/KzBWPW)

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
table thead th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table tbody td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      column1
    </th>
    <th style="width:10px;">
      column2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              data1
            </td>
            <td>
              data2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
      Cell with more data
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @dippas Thanks for your answer. Worked

Comment: @dippas As you have told , i have updated the codepen . It works with IE11 but still fails in IE10. Can you please check it ?